# Laravel Barryvdh Dompdf : Page is not working http 500 error

Tags: laravel-5.4, dompdf

I have I have installed 'barryvdh/laravel-dompdf' using composer and added lines in providers and alias array in config.php

```
Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
```

and

```
'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
```

And created controller and functions and for download files.Its working fine and download pdf on localhost but when I uploaded to server The page is not working its giving HTTP 500 error.